# How to make the drawer take full height of the screen?

Tags: css, antd, ng-zorro-antd, ng-zorro-mobile

How to make the drawer take full height and the three dots button '...' clickable at the same time.
Here is a working demo, when you uncomment line 9 of app.component.ts, the code works fine.
But the drawer isn't taking the full height of the screen.

If I remove the position: relative, the drawer will take full screen, but the three dot '...' on navbar is not clickable, does anyone know how to solve the issue? Why it is not clickable once remove the position: relative?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/drawer-antd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

By reading your question one can assume that what you want is this:

```
.my-drawer {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

When you remove `position: relative;` the drawer overlays the button, so it is just logical that it is not clickable, by applying `pointer-events: none;` you make the drawer not susceptible to clicks, that way you can click the button either way.

But I doubt that this is the behavior you're looking for. So please update your question for more clarity on what are you trying to accomplish, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! This answer is better than the others, but apply pointer-events: none; will make click backdrop to close the draw stop working.

Comment: This is the behavior i wanted: https://stackblitz.com/edit/drawer-antd-tknn4t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Although I do not think I should go this approach

Comment: Ok, then wouldn't it be easier to just move the button or the drawer to the right side? That way it would work the way you want and remain user intuitive or is there a reason you're not doing it by now? Other solution that I can think of is moving the button to the drawer's right side in it's container and positioning it so that it looks like it's in the navbar, then after clicking it would move together with the drawer.

Comment: Yes. The root cause of the issue is caused by z-index. I'll choose the solution I posted if I have to use the ng-zorro drawer. Since currently, we are using ionic with ng-zorro. Maybe I will use the ionic menu instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try set the drawer's visibility to hidden when it's closed.

```
[ngStyle]="{ minHeight: this.height + 'px', visibility: !this.state.open ? 'hidden': 'visible' }"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! BTW, the animation will lose for this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

add `top`  spacing like this in your `.my-drawer`  class:

```
/deep/ .my-drawer {
   //position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   top:45px;
}
```

Comment: I want the drawer to take full-screen height, and meanwhile, the three dots button is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this CSS

```
.my-drawer{top: 0;}
```

Comment: Have you try the stackblitz? the three dots is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vh` (viewport height).
`height: 100vh` will take 100% of your screen's height

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this currently is:

- Making navbar to display absolute
- Making navbar after the drawer element

https://stackblitz.com/edit/drawer-antd-tknn4t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts